# Move Build and Release Pipeline from one organization to another

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have been working in one organization and now we are migrating all from one organization to another.
Can anyone suggest me How Can I Migrate my Build and Release Pipelines from one organization to another?

Comment: Hi Jatin, any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if you need further help with this issue :)

Comment: You can't directly import exported configuration file, You need to change lot configurations as you have change organization, which takes time. It is easier to replicate steps to create Build and Release pipelines in New Organization. @Lance, Thanks for your time and thought.

Comment: Hi friend, would you add your workaround as answer and accept it? So that members could benefit from marked answer and easily find the useful info. And then we can archive this issue for you since it's actually resolved. Thx :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work-around I found this.
You can't directly import exported configuration file, You need to change lot configurations as you have change organization, which takes time. It is easier to replicate steps to create Build and Release pipelines in New Organization.

Answer (score 3):

You can **Export**  and **Import** the Pipelines as a template / JSON.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, But I didn't find "Save as a template" option.

Comment: @JatinDave You don't need the `Save as a template` option, all you need is the `Export` option. The template created from `Save as a template` can't be accessible by another organization, so it's useless for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> Move Build and Release Pipeline from one organization to another.

We can easily move the classic Build/Release pipelines into new Org with the `Export and Import pipeline` options, as `Abhujit` answered above.

However, we still need to modify/fix many configurations to make the newly imported pipelines work. We can't access the Private Agent Pool, Source within old Organization, so we have to do more jobs to fix them.

So if someone only needs to reuse the tasks/steps, it's easier to replicate steps to create new Build and Release pipelines instead of importing the pipelines from another org.

PS: Also, using `Yaml pipelines+templates` in both orgs is also a good choice for reusing tasks.